# Repeated opening hours

Tags: javascript

This code works fine except for one bug: every day that the code is active, it prints a constant out-of-hours text (we are closed; Most zárva) from 16:00 to 16:10 CES time zone. What could be the reason for this. I only noticed this problem in this time.

```
<script>
 var a = document.getElementById("online");
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
var onlineweekdays = {
    0: null, //Vasárnap
    1: [6.30, 16.30], //hétfő
    2: [6.30, 16.30], //kedd
    3: [6.30, 16.30], //szerda
    4: [6.30, 16.30], //csütörtök
    5: [6.30, 15.30], //péntek
    6: null //Szombat
};
var onlinedayWorkingHours = onlineweekdays[n]; //Today working hours. if null we are close

if (onlinedayWorkingHours && (now > onlinedayWorkingHours[0] && now < onlinedayWorkingHours[1])) {
  // check if current time is during or beyond 15 minutes before closing time
if (isFifteenMinBeforeOut2(now, onlinedayWorkingHours[1])) {
    a.innerHTML = "rövidesen zárunk."; 
       a.style.backgroundColor = '#fee599'; 
       a.style.color = '#7f6000';
       a.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
       a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
       a.style.padding = '0 4px';
       a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
       a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
  } 
  else {
    a.innerHTML = "most elérhető."; 
       a.style.backgroundColor = '#e2efd9'; 
       a.style.color = '#538135';
       a.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
       a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
       a.style.padding = '0 4px';
       a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
       a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
  } 
  } else {
     a.innerHTML = "most nem érhető el.";
       a.style.backgroundColor = '#efd9df'; 
       a.style.color = '#c91f41';
       a.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
       a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
       a.style.padding = '0 4px';
       a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
       a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
}

function isFifteenMinBeforeOut2(current, clockout) {
    return current >= clockout - 0.10;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see "Most zárva" in your code, so where is it?

Comment: Just a guess: the var ```now```is created as string and used as float comparator. Maybe it helps casting it to float before using.

Answer (score 1):

> every day that the code is active, it prints a constant out-of-hours text (we are closed; Most zárva) from 16:00 to 16:10 CES time zone.

I suspect this is only a problem between 16:02 and 16:10.

> `6.30`

This isn't the time 06:30. This is the number `63/10`: mathematically, it doesn't behave the same as hours and minutes should.

Instead, store the number of hours (06:30 -> `6.5`) or minutes (06:30 -> `390`). Your `now` code should look something like:

```
var now = d.getHours() + d.getMinutes() / 60;
```

and `onlineweekdays` like:

```js
var onlineweekdays = {
    0: null, //Vasárnap
    1: [6.5, 16.5], //hétfő
    2: [6.5, 16.5], //kedd
    3: [6.5, 16.5], //szerda
    4: [6.5, 16.5], //csütörtök
    5: [6.5, 15.5], //péntek
    6: null //Szombat
};
```

and `isFifteenMinBeforeOut2` like:

```js
function isFifteenMinBeforeOut2(current, clockout) {
    return current >= clockout - 0.25;
}
```

(Note: this version *actually* uses 15 minutes as its threshold.)

[trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735979/5223757) would also solve this issue – but only as long as your closing hours remain at least 15 minutes after the hour. If your closing hours changed to `16.05`, then the original check would check whether the current time was after `15.95` – which isn't a real time! In practice, this'd only give five minutes of warning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this expression:

```
d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
```

At 16:05 this will not produce "16.05", but "16.5".

Solve this by not creating a *string* expression, but a numeric value -- so it has the same type as the values you will compare it with.

Change to:

```
d.getHours() + d.getMinutes() / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

`getMinutes()` doesn't return leading zeroes. So when it's `16:04`, you'll set `now = '16.4'`, not `now = '16.04'`. The comparison with `16.30` will be wrong then.

It would be better to create your times with correct fractions rather than trying to treat minutes as decimal fractions. So use `.50` for half hours rather than `.30`. And calculate `d.getMinutes()/60` to get the fraction from the current time.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("online");
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + d.getMinutes()/60;
var onlineweekdays = {
  0: null, //Vasárnap
  1: [6.30, 16.50], //hétfő
  2: [6.30, 16.50], //kedd
  3: [6.30, 16.50], //szerda
  4: [6.30, 16.50], //csütörtök
  5: [6.30, 15.50], //péntek
  6: null //Szombat
};
var onlinedayWorkingHours = onlineweekdays[n]; //Today working hours. if null we are close

if (onlinedayWorkingHours && (now > onlinedayWorkingHours[0] && now < onlinedayWorkingHours[1])) {
  // check if current time is during or beyond 15 minutes before closing time
  if (isFifteenMinBeforeOut2(now, onlinedayWorkingHours[1])) {
    a.innerHTML = "rövidesen zárunk.";
    a.style.backgroundColor = '#fee599';
    a.style.color = '#7f6000';
    a.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
    a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    a.style.padding = '0 4px';
    a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    a.style.marginLeft = '5px';
  } else {
    a.innerHTML = "most elérhető.";
    a.style.backgroundColor = '#e2efd9';
    a.style.color = '#538135';
    a.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
    a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    a.style.padding = '0 4px';
    a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    a.style.marginLeft = '5px';
  }
} else {
  a.innerHTML = "most nem érhető el.";
  a.style.backgroundColor = '#efd9df';
  a.style.color = '#c91f41';
  a.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
  a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  a.style.padding = '0 4px';
  a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  a.style.marginLeft = '5px';
}

function isFifteenMinBeforeOut2(current, clockout) {
  return current >= clockout - 0.10;
}
```